# Django Request unpacking and render local template more efficiently

Tags: python, django

I tried of writing those vars and stuck them back into the render function of Django shortcut which means write at least 4 times for just one var.

For instance:

```
def foo(request):

  bar = request.GET.get('bar')
  bar += 1
  result = {'bar':bar}
  render('parrot.html', result)
```

It's OK when I write just one var, but when comes to 20 more GET vars, that's totally a disaster.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the type of the return value of `request.GET.get('bar')` is either `str` or `NoneType` instead of `int`, thus you can't simply add it by `1`.

Second, remember there is 'no magic', I'd like to rewrite the code like the following, but there are still four occurrences of `bar`

```
def foo(request):
    try:
        bar = 1 + int(request.GET['bar'])
    except:
        bar = 0
    return render('parrot.html', {'bar':bar})
```

If you don't like this sort of verbosity, just abstract the `try...except` part to a helper such as `get_int`. When there are 20 or more vars to operate on, you may need higher level of abstraction such as [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)...

Comment: Oh, thanks for your heads up! My dumb brain just reminds me that form had to be with models! It's a great solution when getting API called from other server.